# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') - mongoose encrypt

Tags: mongoose, encryption, password-encryption

I'm study authentication and security, and when I started to use encypto to some data fields in the server, this error appears. I tried many ways to fix it, but still unsuccessfull. Please help.

here is the code:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", { useNewUrlParser: true })

const userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});


const secret = "secretKey";
userschema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: secret, encryptedFields: ['password'] });

const User = mongoose.model('User', userschema);
```

The terminal says the error is in:

`userschema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: secret, encryptedFields: ['password'] });`

Help :)

Comment: What is the full error exactly?

Comment: I fixed it already. The title was the full error :/, so I got another encryption package that worked. But thanks for the attencion!!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. Fortunately, I figured out a way.

### The root cause for the issue (in my opinion):

Seems like the plugin method is not sure whether the Schema is present or not. Thus throwing an undefined error.

### Solution

We can use chaining for method execution. This way we can ensure that the plugin method has the prerequisites it needs.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose
  .Schema({ email: String, password: String })
  .plugin(encrypt, { secret, encryptedFields: ["password"]});
```

Hope I helped :)